# Get zrange with score

Tags: python, redis

Is it possible to get a list of tuples of the elements with their score in a ZSET? For example:

```
redis.zrange-function('channel', 0, -1)
[('item1', 123), ('item2', 333), etc.]
```

Comment: Are you using `redis-py`? There's an optional argument `withscores` in `zrange()` to get exactly that output. See the [docs for `zrange()`](https://redis-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/redis/client.html#StrictRedis.zrange).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For `redis-py`, there's an optional argument for that in `zrange()` as per the [docs for `zrange()`](https://redis-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#redis.StrictRedis.zrange):

> `zrange(name, start, end, desc=False, withscores=False, score_cast_func=<type 'float'>)`
>
> Return a range of values from sorted set name between start and end sorted in ascending order.
>
> ...
>
> `withscores` indicates to return the scores along with the values. The return type is a list of (value, score) pairs

Example:

```
In [292]: import redis

In [293]: r = redis.Redis()

In [294]: r.zadd('channel', 'a', 0, 'b', 5, 'c', 8, 'd', 20)
Out[294]: 4

In [295]: r.zrange('channel', 0, -1, withscores=True)
Out[295]: [(b'a', 0.0), (b'b', 5.0), (b'c', 8.0), (b'd', 20.0)]
```